# Cloud Provider SLAs exposed via RESTful APIs

Tags: amazon-ec2, google-compute-engine, azure-virtual-machine, service-level-agreement

I was wondering if any of the major cloud providers (AWS, Azure, Google) exposed their SLAs for virtual machines via a RESTful API.

Basically, I am looking for the information available on these pages:

> https://aws.amazon.com/compute/sla/
>
> https://cloud.google.com/compute/sla
>
> https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/support/legal/sla/virtual-machines/v1_8/

Does anyone know if this information is exposed by any of these providers via a RESTful API?

Many thanks.

I was informed by Azure Support that this service is not provided by them.

Answer (score 0):

On Google Cloud Platform there is no way to check the information that you are asking via REST API.

Can you explain your use case and maybe we can find a workaround?

Best regards

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. My use case is theoretical at the moment. I am designing a service as part of my PhD research which would obtain SLA information from different providers and issue vertical scaling recommendations for multi-cloud deployments based on a weighted list of desired qualities. These qualities would go beyond cost to include service level guarantees specified in SLAs.

Comment: So my question really is: what would be the best way of obtaining this information from different providers? Having an adapter visit the specific pages and parse the HTML seems a bit flaky to me, but I can't think of any other way at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your use case.
Unfortunately there is no way to achieve your use case.

Best regards

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. All the best.